# Copying an exe and composing it as a docker image and making it platform independent

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to create a Docker image, which when run, should install an exe in the specified directory that mentioned in my docker file.

Basically, I need ImageMagick application. The docker file created should be platform independent, say if I ran in windows it should use windows distribution, Linux means Linux distribution. It would be great if it adds an environmental variable in the system. I browsed for the solution, but I couldn't find an appropriate solution.

Comment: What have you done so far? As written, this is extremely broad/vague.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but maybe someone (like me) was still searching.

I ended up using a java-imagemagick docker version from https://hub.docker.com/r/cpaitsupport/java-imagemagick/dockerfile

You can run `docker pull cpaitsupport/java-imagemagick` to get this docker image to your docker machine.

Now comes the tricky part: as I needed to run the imagemagick inside a docker container for my main app. Now you can `COPY` the files from cpaitsupport/java-imagemagick to your custom container. Example :

```
COPY --from=cpaitsupport/java-imagemagick:latest . ./some/dir/imagemagick
```

now you should have the docker file structure for your custom app and also under some/dir/imagemagick/ the file structure for imagemagick. Here are all ImageMagick relative files (also convert, magic, the libraries etc). 
Now if you want to use ImageMagick in your Code you need to setup some ENV variables to your docker container with the "new" path to the ImageMagick directory. Example:

```
IM4JAVA_TOOLPATH=/some/dir/imagemagick/usr/bin \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/some/dir/imagemagick/usr/lib \
MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH=/some/dir/imagemagick/etc/ImageMagick-7 \
MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH=/some/dir/imagemagick/usr/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.5/modules-Q16HDRI/coders \
MAGICK_HOME=/some/dir/imagemagick/usr
```

Now delete (in Java Code) `ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath(imPath);` this part if it is set. So you can use the IM4JAVA_TOOLPATH. 
Now the `ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();` and `cmd.run(op);` should be working.

Maybe it's not the best way but worked for me and I was struggling a lot. 
Hope this helps!

Feel free to correct or add additional info.

Answer (score 0):

You can install (extract files) to the external hosting system using docker mount or volumes - 
however you can not change system setting by updating environment variables of the hosting system from inside of the containers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to Docker world and couldn't get the solution completely. Let me explore on docker mount and volumes, in the meantime can you share me some example Dockerfile for my problem. It would be really helpful.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host

Comment: -v /path:/path/in/container mounts the host directory, /path at the /path/in/container
-v path:/path/in/container creates a volume named path with no relationship to the host.

Comment: Thanks. That really helps, adding to that I have a question. I have used RUN ["yum","install","ImageMagick"]. I believe it will install ImageMagick inside my container.Now I want to set an env variable in my container so that I can use it from my Java code. I believe we can use rpm -ql ImageMagick to get the installation directory. But can we use EXPORT to set the variable?

Comment: You can have a workaround to solve your requirements. Generate a file with all the properties that you want to have it and then put it in the external mounted file system. And then you can read that file using JAVA to have runtime environment variables for your system.